# Google Invisible Recaptcha: Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to implement Google Invisible Recaptcha on a website online after the domain registration on google recaptcha site, I followed the documentation, but not works. When send the form, show the alert error:

```
Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.
```

This is my code (only the interesting points), HTML/JS:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?
onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&hl=it' async defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
<fieldset>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" required/>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Contact!" /> 
</fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var onSubmit = function(token) {

    // ajax call

};

var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('submit', {
        'sitekey' : 'PUBLIC_KEY',
        'callback' : onSubmit
    });
};
</script>
```

and the contact.php file:

```
class Captcha
{

private $key = 'PRIVATE_KEY'; 
public $goo;

public function verify()
{
    $postData = http_build_query(
        array(
            'secret' => $this->key,
            'response' => $this->goo,
            'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        )
    );

    $options = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postData
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);

    return json_decode($response);
}
}

$captcha = new Captcha();
$captcha->goo = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$response = $captcha->verify();

if (!$response->success) {
// not works
}
else {
// works
}
```

I don't understand what is incorrect.
Thanks for help!

Comment: You did change the PUBLIC_KEY to your public key?

Comment: If your site is running locally then use domain name as "localhost" while registering recaptcha if it is deployed then use a valid domain name.

Comment: Also try with clearing history / browsing data,  if there is problem with cookies

Comment: ... yes, I changed the keys. My site is online, not running locally. I clean the clearing history